# Передача по значению в Java

Tags: java

Добрый день. Читал про вызов по значению и натолкнулся на два примера. 1-ый:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] x = {"A"};
        String[] y = x;
        x[0] = "B";
        System.out.print(x[0] + " " + y[0]);
    }
}
```

Тут вроде бы все понятно. Ссылка на строковый массив "y" будет совпадать со ссылкой на массив "x"и произойдет копирование и ответом будет "B B". Но вот второй пример:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "A";
        String y = x;
        x = "B";
        System.out.print(x + " " + y);
    }
}
```

Здесь почему то ответ "B A", хотя я думал что правильный ответ будет "B B". Ход рассуждений был такой же как и в первом примере. Подскажите пожалуйста, что за подвох в этом примере ? Ведь String - это класс, а не тип в Java и в обоих примерах мы создаем экземпляр класса String.

Comment: Вообще-то это вопрос не про передачу параметров...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

В первом случае у вас есть массив (обозначим его `M`, хотя в Java вы не можете обратиться к нему иначе, как через ссылку). Нулевой элемент массива `M` указывает сначала на строку `"A"`, затем на строку `"B"`. И `x`, и `y`, заметьте, ссылаются на *один и тот же* массив `M`. Когда вы меняете данные в массиве через любую из ссылок, вы меняете одни и те же данные.

Во втором случае у нас есть переменные `x` и `y`, которые ссылаются сначала на одну и ту же строку `"A"`, а затем `x` начинает ссылаться на другую строку (`"B"`). Всё просто.

---

Вот вам аналогия. В первом случае у вас есть клетка. И вы, и я смотрим на эту клетку. В клетке сначала сидел белый кролик, а потом туда посадили чёрного кролика. Теперь и вы, и я смотрим на клетку с чёрным кроликом.

Во втором случае клетки нет, я смотрю на белого кролика, вы смотрите на того же кролика, что и я, а потом я отвернулся и стал смотреть на чёрного кролика. Ну да, теперь мы смотрим на разных кроликов.

Теперь замените кроликов на строки, клетку на массив, «смотреть» на «иметь ссылку».

---

Вы не должны искать универсальных простых правил типа «если я меняю вот эту штуку, та тоже поменяется». Или «не поменяется». Или «поменяется, если уровень косвенности больше 1». Рассуждайте о *смысле* операций каждый раз.

---

Не удержался, добавил картинки, о которых говорил @void.

Смотрите. Первый пример:

```
String[] x = {"A"};
```

[image: String[] x = {"A"};]

```
String[] y = x;
```

[image: String[] y = x;]

```
x[0] = "B";
```

[image: x[0] = "B";]

Второй пример:

```
String x = "A";
```

[image: String x = "A";]

```
String y = x;
```

[image: String y = x;]

```
x = "B";
```

[image: x = "B";]

Так понятнее?

Comment: я не могу понять в чем различие , ведь строчка String y = x; присутствует в обоих примерах. Тем более String - это ссылочный тип. Значит ссылка (в обоих примерах), указывает на то, что данные одного массива будут копироваться в другой.  Под "В первом случае у вас есть массив (обозначим его M)" вы имеете в виду пул строк ?

Comment: в первом примере вы изменили объект,  а кто вам сказал что во втором примере вы изменили объект У ?? вы просто изменили ссылку У. объект то вы не трогали.

Comment: Пул строк тут не причём. Вы знаете, что означает `String[]`? Это не `String`. Прочитайте лучше аналогию про кроликов.

И ещё раз, не думайте, что раз и там и там написано «`y = x`», то и вести себя будет одинаково. Думайте о смысле.

Comment: Простите а чем отличается String[] от String ? Я имею в виду, что String - это объектный тип и создав его экземпляр, мы можем указывать  на него.

Comment: Это разные типы. В первом случае вы меняете не всю клетку, а лишь кролика в клетке. Смотрите внимательно на присваивание `x[0] = "B"`.

Comment: Я понимаю вашу аналогию. Просто я немного не понял насчет String. Получается, что String x = "A" - это просто строковый литерал , переменная, а  String[] x = {"A"}; - это уже объект , экземпляр класса String. Извините, просто что то не могу понять и все. Хотя, повторюсь ваша аналогия понятна

Comment: @Drylozav `String x = "A"` - x указывает на объект типа `String`. В свою очередь `String[] x = {"A"}` - x указывает на объект типа массив строк, который состоит из одного элемента типа `String` с индексом 0.

Comment: @Drylozav: String x = "A" присваивает x ссылку на строку, содержащую текст A. Строка является объектом.

String[] x = {"A"} присваивает x ссылку на массив строк, содержащий одну ссылку на строку, которая содержит текст A. Массив строк тоже является объектом. x[0] есть эта самая ссылка на строку.

Comment: @Vlad - замечательно, плюсую! @Drylozav - не сочтите за иронию, не думайте, что Java ведет себя *неправильно*. Я, точнее выражаясь, думаю, что и вы знаете, - я более чем уверен в этом, - что Java не ведет себя *как-то не так*, поэтому я всего лишь хочу сказать, что вы на правильном пути.
Достаньте лист бумаги и начертите то, о чем вам сказал @VladD. Схематично представьте себе. Очертите прямоугольниками *строки* А и В. Начертите массив, элемент которого указывает на строку А. {.пауза.} А затем графически проанализируйте. Коммент не позволяет писать больше. 
P.S. Плюс за вопрос - зачитался сам

Comment: String - иммутабельный объект

Comment: @Sublihim: Да, а что?

Comment: @VladD, видимо комментарий не туда приписал. Поэтому он и печатает "B A" :)

Comment: @Sublihim: А, понял :)

Comment: Думаю, еще понятнее будет, если объяснить, что в строке x = "B"; просто создается новый объект "строка" и сссылка на него присваивается переменной х. Типа x = new String('B');

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець: Если я не ошибаюсь, там немного не так, новая строка не создаётся, а берётся [одна общая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417843/10105).

Comment: @VladD, это уже другая история. Но даже если бы строка "В" уже существовала, то х и у все равно указывали бы на разные области памяти.

Answer (score 6):

В первом случае у вас есть 2 ссылки на один и тот же массив.

```
String[] x = {"A"}; //x указывает на массив {"A"} (x[0] == "A")
String[] y = x; //x и y указывают на массив {"A"} (x == y; x[0] == y[0]; x[0] == "A"; y[0] == "A")
x[0] = "B"; //в массиве {"A"} строка с индекcом 0 поменялась на строку "B", изменилось состояние массива и теперь это массив {"B"}. Но это все еще тот же самый объект (x == y; x[0] == y[0]; x[0] == "B"; y[0] == "B")
```

Во втором же случае у вас две разных ссылки на экземпляры класса String:

```
String x = "A"; //x указывает на строку "A"
String y = x; //x и y указывают на строку "A" (x == y)
String x = "B" //x указывает на строку "B", y указывает на строку "A" (x != y)
```

Comment: Но какая разница ? ведь в первом примере тоже есть две ссылки на экземпляр класса String, которые представлены строковым массивом и как вы сказали есть 2 ссылки, которые указывают на один и тот же массив. В этом примере ведь тоже самое : две ссылки.

Comment: в первом примере НЕТ ссылки на экземляр String. я её в упор не вижу. там есть ссылка на МАССИВ который типизирован String'ом.

Comment: как нет ? ведь String - это класс, любой экземпляр которого порождает объект

Comment: попробуй замени String x = "A" на String x = new String("A")

Comment: @Dryzolav я дополнил ответ. Надеюсь, стало понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Никак невозможно изменить содержимое созданной строки, по крайней мере в безопасном (safe) коде и без рефлексии. Поэтому вы при изменении строк изменяете не сами строки, а значения переменных, указывающих на строки. Например, код s = s.Replace ("foo", "bar"); не изменяет содержимое строки s, которое было до вызова метода Replace — он просто переназначает переменную s на новообразованную строку, которая является копией старой за исключением всех подстрок «foo», заменённых на «bar».

Comment: Не относится к вопросу. Ситуация с изменяемым объектом была бы такой же в случае присваивания.