# Вопрос по поводу результата сравнения 2 строк

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Почему результат выполнения этого кода true false, а не false false?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String x="hello",y="hello"; 

        x += "1";
        y += "1";

        System.out.print(x != y);

        x="hello1";
        y="hello1";

        System.out.print(x!=y);

    }
```

Comment: **Offtopic:** Ненавижу такие вопросы связанные с особенностями реализации языка - они никак не относятся к практическому программированию. Новички почему-то полагают такие вопросы очень важными, постоянно изучают/тренируются на них, а всякие "гуру" изобретают такие вопросы и валят новичков на них. Ненавижу.

Comment: @Barmaley: ну, это типичный и популярный wtf в языке. Нету перегруженных операторов, а C++ (и C#) приучает к ним.

Comment: @Barmaley эмн, а разве человек, пишущий на конкретном языке/платформе, не должен понимать, как этот язык/платформа работает? (Заступаюсь за новичков.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оператор `!=` проверяет ссылочное неравенство, а не неравенство значений.

После выполнения кода:

```
x += "1";
y += "1";
```

вы получаете два разных объекта `"hello1"` в памяти. Соответственно ссылки на них не равны.

Во втором случае в дело вступает [интернирование строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417843/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-interning-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F/417844#417844): переменные `x` и `y` ссылаются на одно и то же значение, поскольку JVM интернирует значение констант.

P.S. Для сравнения значений строк всегда следует использовать [`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). Подробнее [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java/417406#417406).