# Почему ссылки на строки не равны?

Tags: java, строки

Результат выполнения этого кода - false. Почему false, если значения строк одинаковые и инициализируются они не с помощью new, то есть попадают в пул?

```
String s1 = "str";
String s2 = "str";
System.out.println("Result: " + s1 == s2);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что ваше выражение вычисляется так:

```
("Result: " + s1) == s2
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/wqHRbo): вот такой код

```
String s1 = "str";
String s2 = "str";
System.out.println(("Result: " + s1) == s2);
System.out.println("Result: " + (s1 == s2));
```

выдаёт

```
false
Result: true
```

---

(*Дополнение для читателей, не знакомых с интернированием.*)

В Java сравнение ссылочных типов через `==` есть сравнение ссылок на объекты. Разные экземпляры строк с одинаковым содержанием считаются для оператора `==` разными.

Но здесь в игру вступает интернирование: строковые литералы *интернируются* в Java, то есть, они заменяются на общий, один и тот же объект. Поскольку объект один и тот же, сравнение `(s1 == s2)` возвращает `true`. Такая же строка, прочитанная из файла или просто сконструированная заново (`new String("str") == s2`), дала бы результат `false`.

Дополнительное чтение: [Что такое interning и как им пользоваться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417844/10105).