# Применение string.Empty

Tags: c#

Зачем применять `string.Empty`, или в чем его отличие от `""`? И в том, и в другом случаях результат - пустая строка.

Например:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
textBox1.Text = "";
```

На MSDN про первый вариант сказано :

> Значением данного поля является строка нулевой длины, "".

Т.е. то же самое `""`.
Насколько знаю, `Empty` используется только со строками, и полностью повторяет `""`, но ведь зачем-то его в язык ввели. Кто знает зачем?

Comment: _в чем его отличие_ - например: `string.Empty` - это статическое поле, и поэтому не может быть использовано в качестве значения для констант, в то время как литерал пустой строки может быть использован.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or “” to intitialize a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/263191/2881286)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

В .NET2.0+ нет разницы (в плане оптимизации) какой вариант использовать для присваивания и сравнения. Какой считаете более уместным, тот и используйте.

Однако так как `string.Empty` - это `readonly`-поле, а `""` - это константа, то в некоторых ситуациях можно использовать только `""`:

1. В качестве значения по умолчанию параметра метода:

   ```
   void Method(string value = string.Empty) { }
   ```

   приводит к

   > Error: Default parameter value for 'value' must be a compile-time constant
2. В `case` в `switch`:

   ```
   string str = "";
   switch (str)
   {
       case string.Empty: 
            break;
   }
   ```

   > Error: A constant value is expected.
3. В параметрах атрибута:

   ```
   [XmlRoot(string.Empty)]
   ```

   > Error: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

На базе [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151481/3432401) и [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703103/3432401) ответов.

Comment: Мне кажется что string.Empty указывает на одно место в памяти, но не стоит забывать что .net пишут не глупые люди, и тот же самый "" может тоже указывать на одно и тоже место в памяти. чисто мое ИМХО

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, более того: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417844/218063

Comment: @Андрей как интересно .net разруливает это в куче?