# Влияют ли пустые переменные на время работы

Tags: c#, теория

Вот мне стало интересно, влияют ли переменные пустые на работу кода?

У меня возникла хорошая идейка на счет написания собственого Языка Программирования и мне нужно ускорить время работы компилятора.

Там есть много конфигов типа `@version` `@last_update` `@error_list` и некоторые из этих параметров будут пустые. При считывании большого текстовика весом в 0,5 гб вылетело [OutOfMemoryException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx) и я решил убавить условий, переменных и т.д. А потом мне сказали, что переменные не занимают время работы и вес.

**Вопрос:**

Много ли оперативки, времени и места занимают переменные, даже если они пустые?

Comment: например в .net string.empty указывает на один участок памяти. можете просто присваивать им своеобразный nullptr, при определении.

Comment: Что значит пустые? Если переменная типа-значения (`ValueType`/`struct`) - то она не может быть пустой в принципе. Если переменная ссылочного типа ("указатель" на экземпляр класса), то она в любом случае занимает место - размер этого указателя

Comment: Сколько оперативки занимает Int, float, double, класс с 5 стрингами или класс с 10 стрингами? Если вам реально это хочется знать, то хорошо помогает изучение с/c++, а также неплохо изучить принципы работы стековых виртуальных машин (как работает CLR, сборка мусора).

Comment: @pavel1787mego, в плане занимаемой памяти - абсолютно ничем

Comment: нет, ну разве что при записи в переменную значения потребуется на одну машинную команду больше (хотя при записи null скорее всего тоже он явно пишется в память такой же машинной командой)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, обычная `""` указывает на него же. Можешь проверить через Object.ReferenceEquals. Мне неизвестно ни одного способа создать другой экземпляр пустой строки. Даже конструктор new string с указанием 0 повторений любого символа вернёт её же.

Comment: @Qwertiy, здесь написано как это отключить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417844/218063

Comment: @Qwertiy именно так оно и есть. Я указал string.empty чтобы было понятно о чем идет речь

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, но зачем это отключать? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy, я к тому, что `Мне неизвестно ни одного способа создать другой экземпляр пустой строки` - можно ведь отключить и посмотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кратко, то не влияют и не занимают, если сборка выполнялась в конфигурации **Release**, при которой компилятор C# убирает все неиспользуемые переменные, а также "мертвые" ветки кода.

В **Debug** конфигурации такая оптимизация не выполняется для того, чтобы в отладчике можно было посмотреть содержимое "пустых" переменных, а также произвольно перемещать точку выполнения назад/вперед.

Важно также упомянуть, что в C#, в отличие от C/C++, нельзя создать пустую переменную — компилятор потребует её проинициализировать — за это отвечает стадия компиляции Control Flow Analysis.

Любая локальная переменная, если она не убрана компилятором заранее, занимает место в стеке плюс, в зависимости от типа (`value type` или `reference type`) и способа инициализации (ссылка на существующий объект или `new`), еще и в куче.

К примеру, любая переменная ссылочного типа занимает 4 или 8 байт (в зависимости от архитектуры) в стеке. Переменная значимого типа (например, структура) может занимать больше.

Само по себе *наличие* переменной не может влиять на производительность, только на память. А дальше всё зависит от того, что вы с этой переменной делаете.