# Что значит «Строки в C# неизменяемы»?

Tags: c#, .net, строки, память, clr

Пытаюсь понять что значит «строки не «изменяемы»? И казалось бы в этой [статье](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ruericlippert/2011/08/08/653/) автор из кожи вон лез и все по полочкам расставил, но я не понял. И для начала хотел бы понять как примерно выглядит память на разных этапах выполнения ниже представленного кода:

```
string str1 = "string1";
string str2 = str1;
str2 = str1 + "+2";
```

1) И так, после выполнения

```
string str1 = "string1";
```

происходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Далее, после выполнения

```
string str2 = str1;
```

память выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. создается ссылка `str2` которая указывает на новый участок памяти и туда копируется строка из `str1`.

**Я правильно описал этот код?**

Comment: Кстати у нас, кажется, нет каноничного ответа на эту тему. Вот тут немного по касательной: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417843/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я правильно описал этот код?

Нет. `string str2 = str1` здесь вы копируете ссылку в новую переменную. 
 А здесь `str2 = str1 + "+2"` вы создали новый объект. str1 продолжает ссылаться на старый.

Можно проверить равенство ссылок, с помощью ReferenceEquals

```
string str1 = "string1"; //создан первый объект, ссылка на него присвоена переменной str1
string str2 = str1; //ссылка на первый объект присвоена ещё и переменной str2
Сonsole.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(str1,str2)); //true
str2 = str1 + "+2"; //создан второй объект, ссылка на него присвоена переменной str2
Сonsole.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(str1,str2)); //false
```

Строки "неизменяемы" это значит, что несмотря на то, что это объекты ссылочного класса, они имеют признак типов-значений -- *неизменяемость*. Создав один раз объект string вы просто не сможете его изменить, нет ни одного метода для этого.

Даже так `str2[0] = '!'` вы не сможете сделать, компилятор не даст вам изменить объект строки таким способом. А такие методы как Replace, Substring, Trim возвращают новый объект.

Comment: а если я напишу так `"hallow"[2] = 'x'`?

Comment: Я путаюсь в терминах «объект», «ссылка», «значение», «значение ссылки». Можно ли по другому сформулировать твое последнее предложение: "Создав один раз ссылку типа `string`, вы просто не сможете изменить содержимое того куда указывает эта ссылка"?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин то не скомпилируете

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин  получите `Property or indexer string.this[int] cannot be assigned to (it is read-only)`

Comment: @adamshakhabov по большому счету, создав строку в памяти, вы не сможете эту строку изменить. Вы можете иметь сколько хотите ссылок на строку, но сама строка останется неизменной.

Comment: @tym32167 Ясно, интересно почему такой возможности нету, наверное что бы не ломать строчки которые получены так `string str2 = str1;`

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин это связано со многими вещами, например, неизменяемые объекты потокобезопасны.

Comment: @adamshakhabov вроде можно, но мне не нравится термин "ссылка типа string". У вас в коде есть две переменные типа string и два объекта типа string. И вы в третьей строке поменяли объект, на который ссылается переменная.

Comment: @adamshakhabov @4per Просто создание ссылки на строку не то же самое, что создать строку. Вот создание ссылки `string str = null;`, а вот создание строки и ссылки на неё `string str = "asdfg";`

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, проще всего вам будет представить `String` как что-то типа структуры. Да, он может принимать `null`, и в этом его особенность. Но он не предназначен для изменения. Это сделано из соображений безопасности и удобности. Если хотите изменять строку `str[i] = 'b'`, то вам нужен `StringBuilder`. Вот его-то как раз и можно изменять так, как вы писали. Кстати, в нем многие методы похожи на методы в `String`.

**Отличие:** 
Например, при `String.Replace(..)` сама строка, метод которой вы вызываете, не изменится(Зато возвратится новый `String`, который будет уже таким, каким вы хотите).
В свою очередь, при `StringBuilder.Replace(..)` также возвращается новая строка, отвечающая вашим требованиям. Но при этом сам объект `StringBuilder` также изменится. Сейчас приведу пример кода.

```
            string str1 = "12345";
            StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder("12345");
            //В данный момент оба объекта содержат одинаковый массив символов.
            //str1[3] = 'b';//Невозможно так сделать, потому что String доступен только для чтения.(компилятор ругается)
            str2[3] = 'b';//А вот тут все ок, потому что StringBuilder можно изменять, 
            //он для того и создавался, чтобы использовать его как изменяемую строку

            str1.Replace('2', 'c');//str1 не изменился. Просто потому, что так прописано в реализации этого метода.
            str1 = str1.Replace('2', 'c');//теперь str1 указывает на новую строку, которую вернул метод String.Replace(..)

            str2.Replace('2', 'c');//str2 изменился.
            str2 = str2.Replace ( '2', 'c' );//str2 теперь указывает на новый StringBuilder, 
            //который вернул StringBuilder.Replace(..). Это совершенно лишнее, достаточно строки выше.

            /*str1 сейчас: "1c345"
              str2 сейчас: "1c3b5"*/
```

Answer (score -3):

В строке **str2=str1**: если структура *struc* будет передано значение новой переменной str2, а в классе *class* - ссылка.

```
    struc EqualStr 
    { 
      var str1 = "string1"; 
      var str2 = str1; //передано значение
      str2 += "+2";    //str1 = "string1";
    } 

    class EqualStr 
   { 
     var str1 = "string1"; 
     var str2 = str1; //передана ссылка на ту же строку
     str2 += "+2";    //str1 = "string1+2";
   }
```