# String и сравнение через ==

Tags: java

```
    String a1 = "abc";
    String a2 = "abc";
    String str1 = new String("abc");
    String str2 = new String("abc");
```

Почему при сравнении (a1 == a2) результат true, хотя они является объектами и у них разные ссылки, т.е и результат должен быть false. В чём отличие (a1 == a2) и (str1 == str2)?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417843/Что-такое-interning-и-как-им-пользоваться

Answer (score 3):

Потому, что на этапе компиляции для одинаковых литералов будет создан только один объект строки.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a1 = "abc";
        String a2 = "abc";
    }
}
```

Компилируем

```
$ javac Main.java
```

смотрим в байткод

```
$ javap -c Main
```

и видим

```
0: ldc           #2                  // String abc
2: astore_1
3: ldc           #2                  // String abc
5: astore_2
6: return
```

что и для `a1` и для `a2` ссылка в пул констант одна - `#2`

Answer (score 0):

Строки созданные на момент компиляции указывают на один и тот же экземляр, поэтому a1 и a2 - одинаковы. Компилятор создает коллекцию -пул строк, и для созданных на момент компиляции как бы вызыается метод intern().

Для второй пары строк истиной будет str1.intern() == str2.intern()