# Как вывести на экран количество элементов в массиве имеющих конкретное значение?

Tags: c#, массивы

Я создала строковый массив,и рандомно присвоила элементам значения в помощью переменной типа int (0,1) и вывела на консоль "черное" и "белое". Как вывести на экран еще и количество элементов в массиве отдельно с названием "черное" и названием "белое"?

```
int numberOfBalls = 100;
string[] balls = new string[numberOfBalls];

Random rnd = new Random();
int a = rnd.Next(0, 2);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; i++)
{
    a = rnd.Next(0, 2);
    if (a == 0)
        balls[i] = "beloe";
    else
        balls[i] = "chernoe";
}

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(balls[i]);
}
```

Comment: код в студию, будте любезны!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [методом расширения `Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(balls.Count(s => s == "beloe"));
```

Классический вариант сделать тоже самое вручную в цикле:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (string s in balls)
    if (s == "beloe") ++count;
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

С помощью цикла for:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; ++i)
    if (balls[i] == "beloe") ++count;
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Для подсчета количества "черных" код аналогичен.

Comment: Для получения количества черных (при наличии только белых и черных и уже подсчитанном количестве белых) достаточно будет и `numberOfBalls - count`.

Comment: благодарю)!!!!!

Comment: а можно ли это реализовать с помощью цикла for?

Comment: @Marmaid, можно, добавил.

Comment: отлично) спасибо)!

Answer (score 5):

А можно в списке так и хранить 0 и 1 (занимает меньше места в памяти), а проверку черное/белое проводить перед выводом текста.

Тогда сумма черных будет `var black = balls.Sum();` без всяких циклов (т.к. в списке только 0 и 1, то сумма всех элементов даст нам сумму единиц, которая и есть количество "черных" элементов).

А сумма белых: `var white = numberOfBalls - black;`

Comment: ​Изящно​, чё​.​

Comment: А можно и проверки не делать тогда, завести массивчик `{"beloe","chernoe"}` и отдавать по индексу равному значению элемента

Comment: Во, да! Именно так.

Comment: "занимает меньше места в памяти", уверены? :) Тут не все так однозначно, строки - ссылочный тип и благодаря интернированию будут храниться в единственном экземпляре, а в массиве будут лишь ссылки на них. Сравнение тоже будет выполняться быстро, так как ссылки одинаковы. Итого, если иметь массив "индексов" и массив со значениями (как у @yolosora), то расход памяти будет одинаковый. Но вообще - да, согласен, хранить индексы удобнее, а в идеале вообще надо создать класс Ball и работать с коллекцией экземпляров этого класса.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не уверен :) Исходил из того, что хранится один и тот же текст по 50 раз :) Но если хранятся ссылки, а не сам текст, то да, особой разницы может и не быть.

Comment: Вот ссылка по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417843/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP а что если извратиться и заполнить массив запакованными нулями и еднициами?:D

Comment: @yolosora, можно использовать класс BitArray, но тут уже вопрос - что вам важнее 10 Б памяти или 10 нс времени :) Овчинка выделки не стоит, имхо.