# Неизменяемость строк в C#. Что происходит в памяти?

Tags: c#, clr

Я читал уже статьи и ответы на эту тему, но все равно не понял одну вещь.

```
string str = "hello ";
str += "world";
Console.WriteLine(str); // hello world
```

Что происходит в памяти? `str="hello"` диспозится и создается `str="hello world"`?

Comment: Верно. Только диспозится не прям сразу, а в неопределенное время

Comment: А что происходит вот тут: `int a = 0; a = 5;`? Суть та же, `str = str+"world"`;

Comment: Ничего хитрого в памяти не будет, так как компилятор шибко умный, и он создаст сразу одну строку `hello world`.

Comment: В памяти будет все тоже, что и с любым объектом ссылочного типа - если объект недостижим (если грубо - отсутствуют ссылки на объект), то когда-нибудь его уничтожит сборщик мусора или никогда, если свободных ресурсов достаточно или программа завершает работу очень быстро. В любом случае все созданные объекты будут уничтожены при выгрузке домена приложения.

Comment: @Bulson для случая  `str = "hello " + "world"` - да, для приведенного примера почему-то нет, хотя такая оптимизация со стороны компилятора возможна.

Answer (score 2):

Строковые литералы (константы) компилятор [интернирует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417843/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-interning-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) и помещает в [пул строк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BB_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA). Такие строки (в примере `"hello "` и `"world"`) не могут быть собраны сборщиком мусора, о чем говорится в документации [`String.Intern`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern):

> **Performance Considerations.**
>   ... the memory allocated for interned String objects is not likely to be released until the common language runtime (CLR) terminates. The reason is that the CLR's reference to the interned String object can persist after your application, or even your application domain, terminates. ...
>
> ***Соображения производительности***
>   ... память, выделенная для интернированных строк навряд ли будет освобождена до момента остановки исполняющей среды (CLR). Это происходит из-за того что ссылки CLR на интернированные строки могут сохраняться после завершения как приложения, так и его домена. ...

Если в примере использовать не константы, а строки, созданные динамически:

```
//создаем одну строку
string str1 = someObj.Text + "1";
//создаем вторую строку
str1 += someObj.Text;
```

, то их обработка сборщиком мусора ничем не будет отличаться от обработки любых других объектов. Важно только отследить моменты где создаются новые объекты:

```
//создаем один объект
SomeClass obj1 = new SomeClass(...);
//создаем второй объект
obj1 = new SomeClass(...);
```

Единственная ссылка, которая указывает на объект, созданный в первой строке переприсвоена и этот объект теперь доступен для сборки мусора. Освобожден объект будет при следующем запуске сборки мусора, либо при завершении работы приложения, в зависимости от того, что произойдет раньше.

Comment: По поводу интернирования литералов можно ссылочку на документацию?

Comment: @rdorn В [`String.Intern`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern) сообщается следующее: «The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a table, called the intern pool, that contains **a single reference to each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in your program**... » Там же написано, что интернирование [можно отключить](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilationrelaxations#System_Runtime_CompilerServices_CompilationRelaxations_NoStringInterning), но по умолчанию оно включено.

Comment: "А слона-то и не заметил", спасибо