# Сравнение одинаковых строк в C# выдаёт false

Tags: c#

Почему будет выведен false? Можно, пожалуйста, объяснить как можно подробнее?

```
string s1 = string.Format("{0}{1}", "abc", "cba");
string s2 = "abc" + "cba";

Console.WriteLine((object)s1==(object)s2);
```

Более расширенный ответ: [Что такое interning и как им пользоваться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417843/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В последней строке вы приводите каждую сравниваемую строку к object'у. Объекты в с C# являются ссылочными типами и сравниваются соответственно по ссылке. Ваши строки - разные объекты, хранящиеся по разным адресам, и, следовательно, имеющие разные ссылки на них.

Впрочем `string` в C# - ссылочный тип. Следовательно строки по идее должны сравниваться также по ссылкам, и сравнение должно выдавать false даже без приведения к object. Но это не так, поскольку сравнение строк в C# выполняется по значению. Подобное поведение удобно и предпочтительно в большинстве случаев.
Помимо этого стоит отметить и то, что и копируются строки тоже по значению, следовательно при изменении  строки вы на самом деле создаёте новую, а не меняете старую

Answer (score 2):

потому, что ты сравниваешь ссылки на обьекты, а не сами обьекты.

Все reference-type обьекты через `==` сравниваются по ссылке.

Окроме тех типов данных, в которых `==` переопределен. В случае с строками -- этот метод переопределен и сравнивается значение, а не ссылка.

Когда ты сравниваешь
`(object)s1==(object)s2`

то ты используешь оригинальный `==` а не переопределенный. А т.к. это разные обьекты и они находятся в разных местах памяти, вот тебе и возвращает `false`.

Comment: Хорошо,  а почему если эти строки образованы одним способом, допустим, s1 = "abc" + "cba"; s2 = "abc" + "cba";, то тогда выдает true?

Comment: @Hol0ZeN, потому что: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417844/218063

Comment: я расширил ответ

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо!