# Почему double == double false?

Tags: java, float, типы, double

Вот рабочий код. Я знаю, что правильнее сранивать equals, но почему при создании нового Double с тем же значением он ссылается на другое место в памяти, а Long нет.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long firstLong = 1L;
        Long secondLong = 1L;

        Double firstDouble = 1.0;
        Double secondDouble = 1.0;


        System.out.println(firstLong == secondLong);
        System.out.println(firstDouble == secondDouble);
    }
}
```

Comment: "правильнее сранивать equals" -- это неверно. Это как сказать "умножение правильнее сложения". Ни то, ни другое не правильнее, надо просто понимать их смысл и знать, где применять одно, а где другое. В случае с `Long` я бы не советовал использовать `==` для сравнения значений, даже когда заведомо известно, что они попадают в кэшируемый диапазон, поскольку 1) другая версия ява-машины может кэшировать по-другому; 2) чтоб не привыкать.

Comment: Вот [по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417843/10105).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Оптимизации для целочисленных типов. Long, как и Integer значения -128...127 кешируются и хранятся в стеке. Сейчас вроде эти значения можно даже менять.

В случае присвоения значений, выходящих за границы этого диапазона, создаются новые объекты и всё ожидаемо правильно:

```java
Long firstLong = 1L;
Long secondLong = 1L;
System.out.println(firstLong == secondLong); // true

Long firstLong = 128L;
Long secondLong = 128L;
System.out.println(firstLong == secondLong); // false

Long firstLong = 1000L;
Long secondLong = 1000L;
System.out.println(firstLong == secondLong); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

`Long v = 1L;` это шорткат для `Long v = Long.valueOf(1L);`

Если посмотреть на реализацию:

```
public static Long valueOf(long l) {
    final int offset = 128;
    if (l >= -128 && l <= 127) { // will cache
        return LongCache.cache[(int)l + offset];
    }
    return new Long(l);
}
```

то можно увидеть что значения между `-128` и `127` закешированы и не создают новых инстансов.