# Почему String не меняется по второй ссылке?

Tags: java

```
    String first ="A";
    String second = first;
    second = "B";
    System.out.println(first);
```

Почему `first` все равно выводит `A`? Ведь я заменил этот объект другой строкой?

Comment: Гляньте [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/267073/10105), там в точности ваш пример.

Comment: Да, большое спасибо. Этой мой первый вопрос, в будущем попробую более тщательно пользоваться поиском.

Comment: Ничего страшного, поиск, к сожалению, пока не очень хорошо индексирует русский текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная `second` после присваивания указывает на другой объект. `first` на один, `second` на другой.

Comment: Вот сглупил... Могу лишь изменять по ссылке. Запутался слегка. Спасибо.