# ArrayDeque хранит только ссылки на объекты?

Tags: java

Я пытаюсь сделать стек из arraylist'ов, но созданный мною хранит только ссылку на объект, который в него добавили, а я хочу, чтобы он хранил сам объект и размер(и содержимое) `unitPaths` не менялось при изменении `path`

```
Dot a = new Dot();

Deque<ArrayList> unitPaths = new ArrayDeque<ArrayList>();

ArrayList<Dot> path = new ArrayList();

unitPaths.push(path);

println(unitPaths.peek().size()); //printing 2
path.add(a); 
path.add(a);
println(unitPaths.peek().size()); //printing 4
```

Comment: связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/267073/227016

Comment: @diraria я понял, но ответ на вопрос не Дан. Я пытался писать `unitPaths.push(new ArrayList<Dot>(path)`, но это тоже не помогло , хотя я создаю уже новый, казалось бы, ArrayList.

Comment: Ответ, не дан, да. Если в `ArrayDeque` добавлять новый `ArrayList`, созданный через `new ArrayList<>(старый_arraylist)`, то вроде [всё работает](https://ideone.com/lIpGbc).

Comment: @diraria хм. у меня почему-то не работает. Пишу на Processing 3.3.6, там Java.

Comment: @diraria а. я понял, я еще использовал иногда `path = unitsPath.peek()` и получается, что каждый раз меняя path, я менял unitsPath.peek(). Ок, нужно было `path = new ArrayList(unitsPath.peek())`. Спасибо.