# Почему ссылочные типы в C# ведут себя по-разному?

Tags: c#

Обучаюсь языку C#. В процессе его "ковыряния" возник вопрос: почему при передаче массива в метод его изменение отображается во внешнем контексте, а у строки нет, хотя и то и другое - ссылочные типы?

[image: Изменение Массива]

[image: Изменение строки]

Comment: Потому что в первом случае вы меняете сам массив, а во втором только ссылку на строку, сама строка остается без изменений

Comment: @tym32167, как это - меняю ссылку на строку?

Comment: С таким же успехом вы в первом случае можете написать `a = new int[100];` и поглядеть результат

Comment: Ссылочная переменная хранить ссылку на объект. Это как дом и адрес дома - дом это значение объекта, а адрес - это бумажка с адресом где дом находится. Вот тут `a = "abc";` вы просто на бумажке с адресом стираете старый адрес дома и пишете новый адрес нового дома, при этом сами дома никак не меняются

Comment: Вот это же `a[0]=5;` означает `пойди по адресу на бумажке а, зайди в первую квартиру и запиши туда 5` - то есть эта операция меняет значение в массиве, потому вы видите это изменение.

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо большое за объяснение, разложили всё по полочкам.

Comment: к строке вы тоже можете обращаться как к массиву из `char`, но только на чтение `char c = text[3]`, а вот наоборот присвоить не получится, потому что строка - неизменяема.

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/267076/10105

Comment: @VladD Как по мне - дубликат, в этой части различий между java и C# не вижу, строки и там и там иммутабельные. Спросил в чате, нормально ли что ЯП разные, а так вообще не вижу препятствий.

Comment: @VladD не дубликат. тут вопрос про передачу параметров, а не про неизменяемость строк - автор же не пытается поменять содержимое строки, присваивает новую. и в принципе ответ "вы меняете саму ссылку на объект, а не заменяете что-то внутри объекта, используйте ref чтобы изменение ссылки отобразилось во внешнем контексте" был бы уместен. А там - точно нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поменять массив внутри метода не получится, посмотрите:

```
void Main()
{
    var arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    Test1(arr);
    arr.Dump();
}

private void Test1(int[] arr)
{
    arr = null;
}
```

Выведет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот в вашем примере вы меняете не массив, а его элементы - а внутри массива у вас значимый тип (int), он заменяется.

Аналогично и с другими ссылочными типами:

```
void Main()
{
    var book = new Book { Id = 1, Title = "asdf"}; 
    Test1(book);
    book.Dump();
}

private void Test1(Book book)
{
    book.Id = 2;
    book = null;
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Со строками такой вариант не проходит, [потому что строки в C# - неизменяемый тип](https://habr.com/en/post/165597/).