# Почему при изменении второго массива изменяется первый, и что сделать, чтобы первый не изменялся?

Tags: c#

```
var array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var array2 = array1;
for (var i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
    array2[i] += 10;
return array1;
```

Comment: Вы копируете ссылку на один и тот же массив. Почитайте про ссылочные типы.

Comment: См. тж. аналогичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1236791/213987

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что массив - это ссылочный тип.

Есть еще значимые типы. Проще всего отличить ссылочный тип от значимого - это запомнить, к чему принадлежат самые популярные базовые типы. Например `class` - это всегда ссылочный тип, а структура `struct` - это всегда значимый. Например `int` - это структура `struct Int32`, число (`int[]` - это массив `class Array`, не перепутайте).

У вас 2 переменные ссылаются на 1 и тот же массив. Но вы можете создать копию массива, если требуется.

```
var array2 = (int[])array1.Clone();
```

Тогда переменные будут ссылаться на разные массивы.

- [Ссылочные типы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)
- [Значимые типы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)
- [Ссылочные и значимые вместе](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.16.php)